Things Which Are Sold in Numbers Not Ribawiyat
I heard that things which are sold in numbers like for example egg or watermelon which are usually sold based on quantity of numbers rather than weight or volume cannot be ribawiyat meaning If I borrowed today 10 eggs tomorrow creditors can ask for more than 10 eggs.
How correct is this as per fiqh?
